# Prove that if $\phi$ is an isometry, then $\overline \phi = \phi^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, rotations, isometry, adjoint-operators

In the book of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page 233, it is given that

> Let $\dim E = \dim F$ and $\phi:E \to F$ be an isometric (or orthogonal)
>   mapping, then the isometry of $\phi$ implies that  $$(\phi(x), y) =
>  (x, \phi^{-1}(y)) \quad x\in E, y\in F,$$  whence $$\overline \phi =
>  \phi^{-1},$$ where $\overline \phi$ is the adjoint of $\phi$.

However, I can't see how does the isometry of $\phi$ implies 
$$(\phi(x), y) = (x, \phi^{-1}(y)) \quad x\in E, y\in F.$$

Could someone provide a proof and an explanation for that ?

**Note:**

The book defined a isometric mapping as a mapping that preserves the inner product, i.e
$$(\phi(x), \phi(y)) = (x,y) \quad x,y \in E.$$

Comment: Some might claim that the equality you want proved is, in fact, a definition. What do you define as isometry?

Comment: @Tom you are right, I have added the definition of the book.Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Simply write $(\phi(x), y) = (\phi(x), \phi(\phi^{-1}(y))) = (x, \phi^{-1}(y))$. Of course, you need to prove that $\phi$ is an isomorphism first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we note that $\phi$ is an isomorphism because it’s kernel is $\{0\}$ else it won’t be isometric and by the data on the dimension we know it’s onto.
So $\phi^{-1}$ is defined. 
$$(\phi^{-1} \circ \phi(x),\phi^{-1}(y))=(x, \phi^{-1}(y))$$
So we are left to show that the inverse is the adjoint operator but that’s easy because else we won’t have
$$(\phi(x),\phi(x))=(x,x)=(x,\bar{\phi}\phi(x))$$ 
For every normal basis vector

Answer (score 2):

So whenever $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$, we have by the definition that $0=(x,y)$, hence $x=y$ (by assuming inner product, not the semi one), hence $\phi$ is injective, as $E,F$ have the same dimension, $\phi$ is bijective. So $(\phi(x),y)=(\phi(x),\phi(\phi^{-1}(y)))=(x,\phi^{-1}(y))$.